# Trouble with formulation of an analytic geometry question

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding a certain question, so I am asking for an explanation of it. The question is asked in a different language, so my translation will probably be mistake-ridden, I hope you guys can overlook the mistakes (and of course correct them):

Show that for each $ a $ the circle $ (x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2 = a^2 $ touches the axes.

This is literally how the question is formulated, I'm sure that it isn't a hard question so if one of you can explain what they mean by this question I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The equation 
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2 = a^2$$
defines a circle in the plane.  The question just asks you to prove that circle touches the coordinate axes  of the plane.

(Hint for the question: Where is the center of the circle defined by that equation, and what is its radius?)

Comment: The radius is $ a^2 $ and the center is at $ (a,a) $ , is that the answer already? If so, wow, than that is easy (and unclearly formulated)

Comment: That's not the radius.

Comment: I meant the radius is also $a$

Comment: Well, that's not quite an answer - you need to indicate why having a center at $(a,a)$ and radius $a$ makes the circle touch the axes.  But it's the first step in the (short) journey.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take on your question would be to realize that if your circle touches the $Y$ axis, it must do so at a point $(0, y)$. Substitute $x=0$ in the equation of your circle; can you find a value for $y$?  The answer for touching the $X$ axis can be found in a similar way.